# getRelatedModelName - how show other column?

Tags: php, symfony1

In 
**abstract class BaseNewsForm extends BaseFormDoctrine**

i have widget:

```
  'user_id'     => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('User'), 'add_empty' => true)),
```

When i have add new News then i have list choice with ID all Users. How can i make change this list for Lastname?
In table Users i have

```
id | username | name | lastname
```

i know that i must in NewsForm add:

```
$this->setWidget('user_id', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('User'), 'add_empty' => true));
```

but how can i this edit for get Lastname, not ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->setWidget('user_id', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('User'), 'add_empty' => true, 'method' => 'getLastname'));